# Xamarin.Mac cannot write files when Sandbox is enabled

Tags: xamarin.mac, appstore-sandbox, entitlements, nssavepanel

I'm making a file encryption app, but when I submit it to the App Store, if I don't enable Sandbox, it gets rejected when I upload it with Transporter.app.

So, I added Sandbox to `Entitlements.plist` as follows.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
  <true/>
  <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Now I can upload files with Transporter.app without any problems, but now that I have enabled Sandbox, when I try to write files from `NSSavePanel`, the file access seems to be denied as shown below. By the way, I can read files from `NSOpenPanel`.

```cs
var panel = new NSSavePanel();
panel.CanCreateDirectories = true;
panel.ReleasedWhenClosed = true;

panel.BeginSheet(MainViewController.Window, ret =>
{
    panel.EndSheet(MainViewController.Window);
    if (ret > 0)
    {
        DirectoryInfo diParent = Directory.GetParent(panel.Url.Path);
        string DirPath = diParent.FullName;
        string FileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(panel.Url.Path);

        var publicKeyFilePath = Path.Combine(DirPath, FileName + ".pub");
        var privateFilePath = Path.Combine(DirPath, FileName + ".pvt");

        var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
        var publicKey = rsa.ToXmlString(false);
        var privateKey = rsa.ToXmlString(true);

        var xml = XElement.Parse(publicKey);
        xml.Save(publicKeyFilePath);  // <- System.UnauthorizedAccessException

        //-----------------------------------
        xml = XElement.Parse(privateKey);
        xml.Save(privateFilePath);

        rsa.Clear();

        return guidString;
    }
});
```

```cs
xml.Save(publicKeyFilePath);  // <- System.UnauthorizedAccessException
```

Of course, if Sandbox is not enabled, the public key file will be saved without any problem.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Hard to see what is failing here. Show the code for getting the path through the save panel. Also realize that the permission you get is not persisted when your app closes. That would require extra steps

Comment: I have added more detailed source code. Thank you.

Comment: So where is filePath comming from? Also try the unaltered url from the save panel

Comment: I'm sorry. The code is essentially a function, and when I simplified and wrote it, the source of the `filePath` was not shown. The code has been re-corrected. `panel.Url.Path` is the relevant section.

Comment: I think the file path you write to has to be exactly the url you are getting from the savepanel. You are changing it with different extensions but the permission is only granted for the exact url the user choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been solved.

As mentioned in the comments, it seems that the file name specified by the user in `NSSavePanel` was not used as it is, and I generated two files with different extensions, which was caught by the Sandbox limitation.

In this case, I was able to save the desired file by displaying `NSSavePanel` twice in a row and saving the file with the user-specified file name.

```cs
var panel = new NSSavePanel();
panel.CanCreateDirectories = true;
panel.ReleasedWhenClosed = true;

panel.AllowedFileTypes = new[] { "pub" };
panel.BeginSheet(MainViewController.Window, ret =>
{
    XElement xml;
    var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
    panel.EndSheet(MainViewController.Window);
    if (ret > 0)
    {
        var publicKey = rsa.ToXmlString(false);
        xml = XElement.Parse(publicKey);
        xml.Save(panel.Url.Path);  // <- Use the file path selected by the user as is
    }

    panel = new NSSavePanel();
    panel.AllowedFileTypes = new[] { "pvt" };
    panel.BeginSheet(MainViewController.Window, rt =>
    {
        panel.EndSheet(MainViewController.Window);
        if (rt > 0)
        {
          var privateKey = rsa.ToXmlString(true);
          xml = XElement.Parse(privateKey);
          xml.Save(panel.Url.Path);  // <- Use the file path selected by the user as is
        }
    });

    rsa.Clear();

});
```